# View function in my solidity code return nothing when i call it in my react app

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, ganache

```js
  async function see() {
    console.log("See function called");
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
  
    try {
      const result = await contract.getRequestsSender();
      console.log("Data received:", result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while fetching data:", error);
    }
  }
```

Only "Data received:" gets logged onto my console.
I've tried running my contract on remix and everything works fine, i'll show you the .sol code too

```
 function getRequestsSender() public view returns (string memory) {
        string memory text;
        string memory space = " ";

        ShippingRequest[] storage requests = shippingRequests[msg.sender];
        if (requests.length > 0) {
            text = string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.name,
                    space,
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.street,
                    space,
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.city,
                    space,
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.state,
                    space,
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.zip,
                    space,
                    requests[0].pickupAddress.country
                )
            );
        }
        return text;
    }
```

I'm using ganache, and on remix everything works fine when i deploy this contract, all functions work perfectly.